# Execute some logic before and after quiz attempt

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am using  "\mod_quiz\event\attempt_started"  Event observers but i am not getting any result, php error messages or logs.

I am creating own local plugin for leader board functionality but I am stuck in  Event observers call.

In events.php file

```
$observers = array(
    array('eventname' => '\mod_quiz\event\attempt_started',
          'includefile'=> '/local/leaderboard/locallib.php',
          'callback' => 'quiz_attempt_started',
          'internal' => 1
    ),
    array('eventname' => '\mod_quiz\event\attempt_submitted',
          'includefile' => '/local/leaderboard/locallib.php',
          'callback' => 'quiz_submitted_start'
    ),
);
```

In locallib.php

```
function quiz_attempt_started($event) {
    file_put_contents('/local/leaderboard/log.txt', $event);
    //Logic Here
}

function quiz_submitted_start($event) {
    file_put_contents('/local/leaderboard/log.txt', $event);
    // Logic Here
}
```

With debugging on this is the error that moodle shows.

PHP Notice:  Exception encountered in event observer 'quiz_attempt_submitted': Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: PHP catchable fatal error
- line 20 of \local\leaderboard\lib.php: call to default_error_handler()
- line ? of unknownfile: call to quiz_attempt_submitted()
- line 155 of \lib\classes\event\manager.php: call to call_user_func()
- line 89 of \lib\classes\event\manager.php: call to -
 core\event\manager::process_buffers()
- line 2489 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: call to core\event\manager::database_transaction_commited()
- line 92 of \lib\dml\moodle_transaction.php: call to moodle_database->commit_delegated_transaction()
- line 2221 of \mod\quiz\attemptlib.php: call to moodle_transaction->allow_commit()
- line 88 of \mod\quiz\processattempt.php: call to quiz_attempt->process_attempt()
 in E:\Moodle_Boost\03_Execution\04_Tech\03_Source Code\lms\lib\weblib.php on line 3096

Here noting to get error or result. Am I forgetting or doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you increase your plugin's version.php file and run an upgrade? If not, then Moodle will not be aware of the new observers.

Comment: yes I have also increased version in version file.

Comment: Is debugging on? Have you tried using xdebug and putting a breakpoint inside your event handler?

Comment: After debugging on I got "Exception encountered in event observer 'quiz_attempt_submitted': Coding error detected".

Comment: Well, looking at your code, I don't think you can call file_put_contents on an arbitrary object and expect it to work - you probably need to use ob_start(); var_dump($event); $out = ob_get_clean(); file_put_contents('/local/leaderboard/log.txt', $out);